# Why Kernel smoothing function, ksdensity, in MATLAB, results in values greater than one?

Tags: matlab

I have a set of samples, S, and I want to find its PDF. The problem is when I use ksdensity I get values greater than one!

```
[f,xi] = ksdensity(S)
```

In array f, most of the values are greater than one! Would you please tell me what the problem can be? Thanks for your help.

For example:

```
S=normrnd(0.3035, 0.0314,1,1000);
ksdensity(S)
```

Comment: Can you provide a specific example to help reproducing your problem?

Comment: @EitanT I edited the question and provided an example.

Comment: @Alex: and I answered it. Concerning your example: The maximum density of a [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) is `1 / sqrt(2 * pi) / sigma`. In your example `sigma = 0.0314` results in a maximum density of 12.7051. This agrees nicely with the result of ksdensity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ksdensity`, as the name says, estimates a probability *density* function over a continuous variable. Probability densities can be larger than 1, they can actually have arbitrary values from zero upwards. The constraint on probabilities is that their sum over an exhaustive range of possibilities has to be 1. For probability densities, the constraint is that the *integral* over the whole range of values is 1.

A crude approximation of an integral of the pdf estimated by `ksdensity` can be obtained in Matlab like this:

```
sum(f) * min(diff(xi))
```

assuming that the values in `xi` are equally spaced. The value of this expression should be approximately 1.

If in your application you believe this approximation is not close enough to 1, you might want to specify the grid of estimation points (second parameter `pts`) such that the spacing is finer or the range is wider than the one automatically generated by `ksdensity`.